# Silverlight ComboBox and SelectedItem

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I have the following scenario:

1 List which contains the months of the year:

```
public List<String> Months
{
    get
    {
        return m_Months;
    }
}


m_Months = new List<String>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(1900, i, 1);
    m_Months.Add(date.ToString("MMM"));
}
```

1 ComboBox whose ItemsSource is bound to the Months-list and whose SelectedIndex is bound to the property Month, which is  a string:

```
public string Month
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Month;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != m_Month)
                {
                    m_Month = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Month");
                }
            }
        }

<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Month, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Months}" />
```

When I set the Year from the codebehind, i.e. Month = "May", this is properly propagated to the ComboBox, and the getter for Month is accessed, but the ComboBox doesn't show 'May' as it's selected item.

I'd like to know: is this a bug in Silverlight 3? It works fine when I use the RadComboBox from Telerik.

Cheers,
Frances

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. Tried your suggestion already and get the same results. However, I've just had a Homer Simpson moment (Dôh!) and found out that I set the Month before the ComboBox sets it's ItemsSource.

Strange, though, that the RadComboBox does everything correctly. Maybe it retrieves the SelectedItem again when the ItemsSource changes.

**EDIT:**

OK, I just literally fell off my chair with amazement. Apparently, SL3 still has some bugs that need fixing. Feast your eyes on the following...

This doesn't work:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Month, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Months}" />
```

And this does:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Months}" SelectedItem="{Binding Month, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

See the tiny difference? As long as I set the ItemsSource **before** the SelectedItem in the XAML, all is well in the world. Wowee, I never knew XAML was parsed linearly!

Comment: Hopefully they have it fixed in Silverlight 4, but thanks for posting this answer.

Comment: Wow, we wasted a lot of time trying to figure this out.  Thanks for posting the answer!

Comment: @Kevin This is not fixed in SL4.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the `Month` property? I'm not sure how the `ComboBox` determines if two items are the same or not, but I could see that it wouldn't work correctly if you pass in "May" rather than `Months[4]`. As a test, you could try passing in one of the strings from you list to see if that fixes the problem or not.