# ComboBox selected item text disappears when scrolling listbox

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, combobox, listboxitem

I have Combo boxes inside a list box and whenever the list box is scrolled and the combo box is scrolled off of the screen the list box is firing a selection change event on the combo box and setting the selected index of the combo box to null.

If I scroll back and forth multiple times you will see the selected item display and be removed by scrolling the list back and forth.

Does anyone have an idea on ow to fix this?  I need the combo box to retain the selected index.

I have even changed the collection that holds the Combo-box data to a list from an observable collection and it still does the same thing.

I am using silver light v4, .net 4

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a result of the default virtualising nature of the `ListBox`.  As items scroll off the displayed  the items are actually removed from the Visual Tree.  If you don't have too many items in the list set the `ItemsPanel` property of the `ListBox` to an `ItemsPanelTemplate` containing a simple `StackPanel`.

Better would be to cease using the selection change event in this scenario, use a binding on the `SelectedItem` property instead.

Comment: One of the problem I am facing is that the entire list contents is generated dynamically using template selectors.  I then also have to drive dynamically created drop down based on a parent drop down box.  I need to use selection changed because I cannot bind it in XAMl as it is a purely dynamic list content.

The template contains different controls based on the display type.

Would a datagrid work better?  Or is it implemented the same as a listbox when the item scrolls off screen?

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but with a datagrid.
I tried this (preferable solution), but it didnt work for me.

[Silverlight ComboBox and SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967913/silverlight-combobox-and-selecteditem/967958#967958)

So i had to go with this....

http://forums.silverlight.net/post/396922.aspx